# How to convert "3.days" into the string "3 days" in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to convert a simple "3.days" string into something that prints "3 days" on screen that will use the appropriate locale depending on the language to print the word.

I guess there's probably an easy way to do this on Rails that I can't seem to find.

Comment: Where is the input coming from?  Whats the range of values possible?

Comment: It comes from a string field in the database. Values can be in the sort of `"3.days"` , `"5.minutes"`, `"1.year"`, etc.

Comment: Do users provide those?  My point is, you would never want to do eval on those fields unless you had super tight control over the values.  I'd go with the gsub option

Answer (score 11):

Call `inspect` on the result. It's been overwritten to return the string `"3 days"`:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.6)
irb(main):001:0> 3.days.inspect
=> "3 days"
```

Behind the scenes, `3.days` is just returning the number of seconds in that time period:

```
irb(main):001:0> puts 3.days
259200
```

If you're storing that integer value, you can go back to `3` you started with by dividing the number by the number of seconds in one day:

```
num_days = 3.days / 1.day
puts "#{num_days} days" # 3 days
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself better: the origin is a string `"3.days"` not `3.days`. So `"3.days".inspect` returns `"\"3.days\"" `. Not sure how that sounds my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the input as a string and the output needs to be a string too, one solution would be to use gsub to replace '.' with ' '

```
1.9.3p194 :004 > '3.days'.gsub('.', ' ')
 => "3 days"
```